# Translate from SQL to Linq

Tags: sql, linq

I'm really new with this whole Linq story, but I have a good understanding in SQL.

I need to rebuild a query from SQL to Linq. My SQL query is working perfectly and so far I have tried to do something by myself with Linq but without a good result...

Is it possible that someone could help me to translate this query from SQL to Linq?
I'm really ready to learn something new in this whole story. It would be nice if you could why is it working like that in linq.

SQL Statement

```
SELECT TimeReport.EntryDate
     , SUM(TimeReport.Hours) AS Hours
     , SUM(BillingRate.HourlyRate * TimeReport.Hours) AS Amount
FROM BillingRate 
    INNER JOIN Activity 
        ON BillingRate.BillingRateId = Activity.BillingRateIt 
        INNER JOIN TimeReport 
            ON Activity.ActivityId = TimeReport.ActivityId 
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN Dossier 
                    ON TimeReport.DossierId = Dossier.DossierId
                    INNER JOIN LBU 
                        ON Dossier.LBUId = LBU.LBUId 
                    INNER JOIN BU 
                        ON Dossier.BUId = BU.BUId 

GROUP BY TimeReport.EntryDate
HAVING SUM(TimeReport.Hours) > 0
ORDER BY TimeReport.EntryDate desc
```

What I have tired with Linq

```
var x = (from br in ctx.BillingRate
                    join a in ctx.Activity on br.BillingRateId equals a.BillingRateIt
                    join tr in ctx.TimeReport on a.ActivityId equals tr.ActivityId

                    select br)
                  .GroupJoin(
                     (from d in ctx.Dossier
                       join l in ctx.LBU on d.LBUId equals l.LBUId
                       join b in ctx.BU on d.DossierId equals
```

Thanks for help and fast answer.

I appreciated every effort !!

Comment: So what is issue with your linq query?

Comment: @AshReva I dont know how to continue

Comment: Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240840/linq-to-sql-equivalent-of-sum-group-by-sql-statement

Comment: Have you tried with LinqPad ? It's a great apps to help you to create Linq queries... http://www.linqpad.net/

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063724/convert-sql-query-with-group-by-and-having-clause-to-linq-to-sql-query-in-c-shar

Comment: @AshReva It would be way easer for both of us  to help me with my query than posting me some answer to different question

Comment: You could try yourself with links i provided as you only said you wanted to learn.

Comment: Also i am not doing anything intentionally. If the links provided by me doesnt work then post that code

Comment: @AshReva What do you mean that instantly posted my question without searching in the internet ... If this links would help I would be done for days ...

Comment: @Mingebag First of all forgive me if i sound arrogant to you. If you could have said that you have already gone through links then i would have said nothing. Even i am not that much expert in Linq but thought the link i provided were quite closer to what you were looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joins aren't necessary when you have navigation properties.  Since I don't know exactly what your model looks like, use the following as a starting point and adjust to your own specifications:

```
// starting with Dossier handles the right outer join condition
var timeRecordQuery = 
        from d in ctx.Dossier
        from tr in d.TimeReports
        // this handles the inner join conditions after the right outer join
        where d.LBUId.HasValue && d.BUId.HasValue
        // project what you want to use
        select new 
        {
            EntryDate = tr.EntryDate,
            Hours = tr.Hours,
            // simply use navigation properties, no need to join
            Amount = tr.Activity.BillingRate.HourlyRate * tr.Hours 
        };

var resultsQuery = from e in timeRecordQuery
                   // group by EntryDate
                   group e by e.EntryDate into g
                   // get sum of hours for each EntryDate value
                   let hours = g.Sum( x => x.Hours ) 
                   // having clause
                   where hours > 0
                   // project results
                   select new 
                   {
                       EntryDate = g.Key,
                       Hours = hours,
                       Amount = g.Sum( x => x.Amount ) 
                   };
```

Comment: but what happens with the Inner Joins (Activity)$ ?